# Filling gaps in pairs of start/end dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Condition:

```
Start date: 31-12-2012  
End date:   01-04-2013
```

- module represents `project_id`
- loading represents that between `module_start_date` and `module_end_date` and `user_id=6` is 40 percent free.

```sql
SELECT [user_id], module_id, module_start_date, module_end_date,
            1 - loading_percentage loading
FROM module_user_master_map
WHERE module_start_date >= '2012-12-31'
      AND module_end_date <= '2013-04-01'
      AND [user_id]=6
```

Using this query I get the following output:

```
user_id | module_id | module_start_date | module_end_date | loading
-------------------------------------------------------------------    
6       | 3         | 01-01-2013        | 31-01-2013      | 0.4
6       | 4         | 15-02-2013        | 28-02-2013      | 0.2
6       | 5         | 01-03-2013        | 15-03-2013      | 0.7
6       | 3         | 30-01-2013        | 30-01-2013      | 0.5
```

If you carefully look at the output you'll observer that user is 100 percent available in date `01-02-2013` to `14-02-2013` i.e his loading is 1.

//corrected dates in above sentence.

I want the output as following

```
user_id | module_id | module_start_date | module_end_date | loading
-------------------------------------------------------------------
6       | 3         | 30-01-2013        | 30-01-2013      | 0.5
6       | 3         | 01-01-2013        | 31-01-2013      | 0.4
6       | Null      | 01-02-2013        | 14-02-2013      | 1
6       | 4         | 15-02-2013        | 28-02-2013      | 0.2
6       | 5         | 01-03-2013        | 15-03-2013      | 0.7
6       | Null      | 16-03-2013        | 01-04-2013      | 1
```

I do have a function which gives me date from start date and end date.

Comment: You tagged this with both mysql and sql server, what rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this approach:

Left join the days you have with the days from the date table function within your the min/max range. (Since you already have a date table function, I will omit that code)

Say I have results for week 1 and week 3, when I left join these 
on all days in January, you can easily see where the gaps are.

```
DECLARE @from DATETIME2(1) = '2013-01-01'
DECLARE @to DATETIME2(1) = '2013-01-31'

DECLARE @from_wk1 DATETIME2(1) = '2013-01-01'
DECLARE @to_wk1 DATETIME2(1) = '2013-01-07'

DECLARE @from_wk3 DATETIME2(1) = '2013-01-15'
DECLARE @to_wk3 DATETIME2(1) = '2013-01-22';

WITH    OccupiedDays ( [dt] )
          AS ( SELECT   B.[dt]
               FROM     DateTable(@from_wk1, @to_wk1) B
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   C.[dt]
               FROM     DateTable(@from_wk3, @to_wk3) C
             )
    SELECT  A.[dt]  AS AllDays,
            OD.[dt] AS OccupiedDays
    FROM    DateTable(@from, @to) A
            LEFT JOIN OccupiedDays OD ON A.[dt] = OD.[dt]
```

Results in:

[image: sql output]

All you need now is to fill out the null values and do some grouping and/or aggregations.

Comment: The issue is that i have many users at a time and i have to group all of them together and also their occupancy will change repectively